# Sprite passing by reference result in null pointer exception using andengine GLES2

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

When I pass sprite in parameter and initialize that object in method but reference of Object is still null which I passed in method. Here is my Method.

```
public void createAndLoadSimpleSprite(Sprite sprite ,String name,
        SimpleBaseGameActivity activity, int width, int height) {

    BitmapTextureAtlas atlasForBGSprite = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            activity.getTextureManager(), width, height);
    TextureRegion backgroundSpriteTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(atlasForBGSprite, activity, name, 0, 0);
    sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundSpriteTextureRegion,
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    activity.getTextureManager().loadTexture(atlasForBGSprite);

}
```

and here how I am calling it.

```
createAndLoadSimpleSprite(defualtCageSprite,"bg.png", this, 450, 444);
```

but accessing defaultCageSprite still throws a null pointer exception... I am not if sure it's a AndEngine issue. But Can't we pass sprites as parameters in AndEngine if no what is the work around??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your method to return the sprite object:

```
public Sprite createAndLoadSimpleSprite(String name,
    SimpleBaseGameActivity activity, int width, int height) {

BitmapTextureAtlas atlasForBGSprite = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
        activity.getTextureManager(), width, height);
TextureRegion backgroundSpriteTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
        .createFromAsset(atlasForBGSprite, activity, name, 0, 0);
activity.getTextureManager().loadTexture(atlasForBGSprite);

Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundSpriteTextureRegion,
        activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

return sprite;

}
```

Now you can call:

```
defualtCageSprite = createAndLoadSimpleSprite("bg.png", this, 450, 444);
```

Do not forget to attach your sprite to the `scene`.

Comment: Yes I changed this method exactly the same way.. But I need to pass sprite in constructor of my class so that every object has its own sprite reference. So I want to pass Sprite as Reference.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, but this is a JAVA problem, try adding a `java` tag to your question.

Comment: You are right. My bad :). Again Ignored the scope of variable :). thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thst is not an AndEngine problem. You are dealing with the way Java works. AFAIK it is not possible to have an output parameter. What you need to do is use "return" or create fields to save your data.